# Cannot work with mysql Ver 11.18 Distrib 3.23.55, for suse-linux

Tags: mysql

An older TYPO3 (v4.4.15) database appears to corrupt a local sandbox MySQL 5.7 schema.  The server hosting the CMS says

```
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 11.18 Distrib 3.23.55, for suse-linux
```

Details: Installing the legacy version of CMS locally allows the creation of a database and/or populates it with tables.  An admin user's credentials can be created and the admin user can successfully log in to the CMS backend. The host's PHPMyAdmin (v4.0.5) is used to dump the live site's database. The local database is then updated using the local system's PHPMyAdmin (v4.6.5) and the dumped script. Although the import succeeds, the admin user can no longer log in. Even creating admin credentials after import does not allow this new admin user to log in.

The legacy database has the latin1 character set.  Even if the local system creates an empty database with latin1 the login fails after import.

How to get the local sandbox of the CMS to use the live site's pages and working admin credentials? [Should this question be moved?]

#### Edit:

I found [this link](http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=542) that discusses how to migrate MySQL from 3.23 to MySQL 5. Unfortunately, the shell id I have for the host fails with

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

when attempting `$ mysql -u {username} -p`

#### Edit #2:

It is likely that the db in question is instead in version 5.5 since that is what phpmyadmin says to `select version();` I'm converging instead on an import error due to an improperly escaped serialized array. The attempt to build a sandbox will now focus on figuring out how best to import such arrays.  (The uncompressed script is about 45MB.)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990708/error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysq

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, that solution seems to require root privileges that I don't have..

Comment: Just file up a virtual machine with full privileges... update the DB and then once updated import it back to the live server. I wouldn't even mess around with MySQL command-line on a server that you don't have root. Alternatively you could try mysqladmin -u username -p instead.

Comment: The database is on a remote host so a virtual machine doesn't seem possible.  And `mysqladmin: command not found` is what I get with the alternative.

Comment: And why can't your export the DB and then copy it to a VM?

Comment: I had tried that: exported with phpmyadmin, ftp to local WIndows system, ftp to existing Ubuntu VM, ran process as described in link above, returned filtered sql to Windows and pointed CMS to db created from that script.  Login still failed.  What stumps me is that I can do admin login with a fresh CMS install but even importing all but the users table kills login. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree!